# Scanning an input string (such as "eeeeexxxxx") and both skipping and handling one character at a time

Tags: java

I couldn't find a "nextChar" method sadly so kind of lost. I need to be able to handle each single letter, yet not skip past it and just handle it after.

Is the easiest method to skip past, split it, sort by index in a "String[] lines" and reset scanner?

```
for (int radCounter=0;radCounter<radFormat;radCounter++) {
        int kolonneCounter = 0;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            if (sc.next().equals("#")){
                SvartRute ny = new SvartRute(radCounter, kolonneCounter);
                nye[radCounter][kolonneCounter] = ny;
            }
            else if (sc.next().equals(".")) {
                HvitRute ny = new HvitRute(radCounter, kolonneCounter);
                nye[radCounter][kolonneCounter] = ny;
            }
            kolonneCounter++;
        }
        radCounter++;
    }

    Labyrint lab = new Labyrint(nye, radFormat, kolonneFormat);
    return lab;
```

Comment: Please show us a [mre] of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based of the little information you've given us, I assume you have a `Scanner` that is reading some sort of input and you need to be able to do something with every char it gives you.

In that case, do this:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    for (char c : scanner.nextLine().toCharArray())
        // Do something
```

Okay, now that you've added your code, for a more detailed explanation:

Instead of this:

```
if (sc.next().equals("#")) {
    // Stuff
} else if (sc.next().equals(".")) {
    // Stuff
}
```

You put the `for`-loop above in your `while`-loop and complete the checks like this:

```
for (char c : scanner.nextLine().toCharArray())
    if (c == '#')
        // Stuff
    else if (c == '.')
        // Other stuff
```

Comment: I apologize, I added some code but since most of my question was in code I did not have, I figured it wasn't much of use to post my code.

Comment: Great. Now, what exactly isn't working with that code?

Comment: sc.next() equals to the whole string token, not every single character. I didn't find a "nextChar" method built into Java, so I didn't know the best optimalization of this issue.

Comment: didn't test comprehensively but looks solid! Thank you and curse the lack of nextChar!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211885/discussion-between-lowkeybuddhist-and-schred).